# What uncertainties and questions surround the death of Attila?

Tags: roman-empire, byzantine-empire

[Merriam-Webester's Concise Encyclopedia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attila) says

> Attila died on his wedding night, **possibly** murdered by his bride.

What uncertainty does the word **possibly** imply there about the death of Attila?

Answer (score 1):

The other source is a recent book by a philologist who argues from literary analysis that Attila was actually murdered. See http://worldhistoryconnected.press.illinois.edu/3.3/br_may.html for a sympathetic review of the book. However, the review also points out some of the weaknesses in Babcock's theory.

Since no new evidence is likely to come up, the jury will probably have to remain out on this on. So it is quite understandable that the Britannica chose to apply Occam's razor to this question.

Comment: Mildly confused: how does adding the qualifier "possibly" constitute applying Occam's razor? BTW, in the Nibelungen saga (at least in Fritz Lang's 1924 [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Nibelungen) version) Attila (aka King Etzel) marries Kriemhild of Burgundy (who is also Siegfried's widow), and he alone is going to survive her entire clan as tragedy unfolds ...

Comment: @Drux Look up the pevious version of the question... :)

Comment: Thx, mystery solved now :)